# Count pairs of elements in an array whose sum equals a given sum (but) do it in a single iteration(!)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, hashmap

Given an array of integers, and a number ‘sum’, find the number of pairs of integers in the array whose sum is equal to given ‘sum’ in a SINGLE iteration. (O(n) Time complexity is not enough!).

Usually, I would iterate twice through the array once to create hashmap of frequencies and another to find the number of pairs as shown below

```
def getPairsCount(arr, n, sum): 
    m=defaultdict(int)      
    for i in range(0, n): #iteration NO. 1
 
        m[arr[i]] += 1

    twice_count = 0 
    for i in range(0, n): #iteration NO. 2
    
        twice_count += m[sum - arr[i]] 
        if (sum - arr[i] == arr[i]): 
            twice_count -= 1
    return int(twice_count / 2)
```

I was asked to do the same in a single iteration instead of two by an interviewer. I am at loss how to do it wihout breaking it at edge cases like {2,2,1,1} where required sum is 3.

Comment: There is a common trick against such a silly requirement: write the program recursively. This way, it looks like you're only iterating through the array once. But recursion actually allows you to go through the array twice.

Comment: @Stef, woud it be time-efficient? The interviewer was talking about how iterating twice won't be efficient.

Comment: @No, it wouldn't. Recursion in python is awful. Actually, your algorithm is good; you can easily combine the two loops into one without changing it too much. The trick is to notice that instead of counting all pairs then dividing by 2, you can count only pairs whose indices (i, j) satisfy i < j. The cool thing here is that when you reach j, i is already in your hashmap.

Comment: Also note that `m=defaultdict(0)` is wrong. `defaultdict` expects a function that returns the default value; it should be `m=defaultdict(lambda:0)` or, even better, `m=defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: @Stef, Understood! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, doing it in one loop removes the need to check for `if (sum - arr[i] == arr[i]): twice_count -= 1` if you do things in the right order; because you can check for `sum-arr[i]` in the hashmap before adding `arr[i]` to the hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to build the hash map at the same time as you are consuming it (thereby only looping the list once). Thus, for each value in the array, check if you have seen the complement (the value needed for the `sum`) before. If so, you know you have a new pair, and you remove the complement from the seen values. Otherwise you do not have a sum and you add the value you have just seen.

In code this looks like follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_pairs_count(array, sum): 
    pairs_count = 0

    seen_values = defaultdict(int)
    
    for value in array:
        complement = sum - value
        if seen_values[complement] > 0:
            pairs_count += 1
            seen_values[complement] -= 1
        else:
            seen_values[value] += 1
    
    return pairs_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def pair_sum2(arr, k):
if len(arr)<2:
    return
seen=set()
output=set()
for num in arr:
    target=k-num
    print("target",target)
    if target not in seen:
        print("seen before add",seen)
        seen.add(num)
        print("seen",seen)
    else:
        output.add( (min(num, target), max(num, target)) )
        print("op:",output)
print ('\n'.join( map(str, list(output)) ) )
```